# Rsync creating diff directories

Tags: rsync, backup

**What I want:**

I'm trying to back up many files to S3 each day. I want to compress these into archives daily so that each individual backup doesn't cost as much. Therefore, I want a backup system whereby I can create differential archives from the previous day to be backed up to S3.

My current reasoning is to create an initial backup, and then base backups per day that are differential wrt that initial backup.

---

**Example:**

Say I have a directory named `dir` containing a file, `a.txt`:

```
dir:
  a.txt
```

Then let's say I run `rsync -r dir backup.1`, or some other backup program, such as, but not limited to, `rdiff-backup`. Great stuff, I have a backup located at `backup.1`.

Now, I add one file, `b.txt`, so that `folder`'s contents is as follows:

```
dir:
  a.txt
  b.txt
```

Is there an `rsync`, or another backup utility, command I can run that will give me a separate directory, `backup.2`, that contains only the file `b.txt`?

If I modify the permissions of `a.txt`, will that file also be included?

**What I've tried**:

I've tried `rsync` and `rdiff-backup`, with a range of flags, but I cannot get anywhere. I've been doing it for *hours* now, and I cannot figure it out.

---

**EDIT:**

Halfway there!

```
rsync -n -rpgov backup/ backup-copy/
```

Please note the `-n` means this does a dry-run,, so you can happily test this without wrecking your own local directories with file changes.

This outputs the difference between two local folders. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this output, through `rsync`'s options, to a new directory.

I've tried using `rsync`'s `--compare-dest` flag:

```
rsync -n -rpgov --compare-dest=backup/ backup-copy/
```

but this seems to output different files to the above command.How to push this over the edge?

Comment: Are the leading dashes part of the filenames, e.g. `- a.txt` ?

Comment: Is your rationale for having backup trees of changed files so that you save disk space? (If so, what's wrong with `rsnapshot` and its hard linked files?) How would your partial backup tree represent a deleted file or directory?

Comment: @roaima It isn't for saving file space. I create a lot of individual files (in the hundreds of thousands) that need to be backed up. We get charged in S3 per GET/PUT request, and it's becoming prohibitively expensive. Having one archive makes the process significantly cheaper

Comment: @roaima The leading dashes are not part of the filename

Comment: Thanks. Your comments about S3 costs would be really useful in your question as background information. It's the sort of information that can help direct someone to a most useful suggestion.

Comment: @roaima Thank you for suggestion! I'll edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer!

```
rsync -rpgov --compare-dest=/home/nick/docs/test/backup-copy backup/ backup-output/
```

Note the complete path, and the lack of trailing slash at the end of the `--compare-dest` flag. This made the difference!